# Marked value to a input field in text area

Tags: javascript, ironpython, spotfire

[Marking in the first table will pass any of the column value in the marked row to input field property control in the text area b/n two tables and after clicking the button beside the property control it will get data on demand from B table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8USGd.png) I am looking to implement the following use case.
I am having two tables in data base like A & B
created 2 cross table visualizations .
Based on the selection in first cross table the data in the second cross table has to be populated(data on demand based on Marking)

But the case is once i mark some thing in the first cross table a particular value has to go in to the input field property control in the text area .
and then on a button click it will pass value to the B table in data base and get data for the second cross table .

i have a problem in getting marked data into the input field property control in text area.Can anyone help me in this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your page so far Rama and explain what value you want to go from the first table into the input field, is it the value from one of the columns of the marked row?

Comment: Hi RyanfaeScotland,please look into the sample image attached,Thans